# How can I add a variable number of custom hover fields, with respect to node, on a HoloViews plot? (python and bokeh backend)

Tags: python, hover, networkx, bokeh, holoviews

I'm working on getting interactive networks so I can send datasets around to collaborators. I've found that [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Network_Graphs.html) is the most intuitive option for interactive networks.  I'm using [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html) for the backend not for any reason other than that's what the tutorial above used and I'm pretty familiar with it.

I've gotten the hover tool to work for my network and it looks great.  Below is an adaptation of the methodology using the iris dataset for the sake of this post.

What I'm having trouble with is getting custom hover fields in addition to the ones already shown.  For example, I want all the nodes to have the `[Node, Species]` fields from the `df_nodes` DataFrame.  However, in the second part of the code underneath the figure I generate custom fields per node that range from 0-5 categories.  I would like to append this onto the existing Hover options.

For example, `iris_1` would have the following where `*` indicates what is already there and `#` indicates what needs to be added:

```
*  Node   iris_1
*  Species    Setosa
#  Category_2    0.734694
#  Category_9    0.489796
#  Category_8    0.469388
#  Category_4    0.122449
```

`iris_2` would only have `[Node, Species]` since it has 0 categories (if you index the `node_to_custom` dictionary you will see that).  `iris_3` will have the `[Node, Species, Category_4, Category_5]` fields.

**How can I add a variable number of custom hover fields, with respect to node, on a HoloViews plot?** Preferably with Bokeh but if Plot.ly is the better option for this, then let's do it.

I tried doing line breaks but they didn't render.  Though, that was supposed to be a hack and not what I actually wanted.

```
# Iris
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

defaults = dict(width=500, height=500)
hv.opts.defaults(
    opts.EdgePaths(**defaults), 
    opts.Graph(**defaults), 
    opts.Nodes(**defaults),
)

X_iris = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': {'iris_0': 5.1, 'iris_1': 4.9, 'iris_2': 4.7, 'iris_3': 4.6, 'iris_4': 5.0, 'iris_5': 5.4, 'iris_6': 4.6, 'iris_7': 5.0, 'iris_8': 4.4, 'iris_9': 4.9, 'iris_10': 5.4, 'iris_11': 4.8, 'iris_12': 4.8, 'iris_13': 4.3, 'iris_14': 5.8, 'iris_15': 5.7, 'iris_16': 5.4, 'iris_17': 5.1, 'iris_18': 5.7, 'iris_19': 5.1, 'iris_20': 5.4, 'iris_21': 5.1, 'iris_22': 4.6, 'iris_23': 5.1, 'iris_24': 4.8, 'iris_25': 5.0, 'iris_26': 5.0, 'iris_27': 5.2, 'iris_28': 5.2, 'iris_29': 4.7, 'iris_30': 4.8, 'iris_31': 5.4, 'iris_32': 5.2, 'iris_33': 5.5, 'iris_34': 4.9, 'iris_35': 5.0, 'iris_36': 5.5, 'iris_37': 4.9, 'iris_38': 4.4, 'iris_39': 5.1, 'iris_40': 5.0, 'iris_41': 4.5, 'iris_42': 4.4, 'iris_43': 5.0, 'iris_44': 5.1, 'iris_45': 4.8, 'iris_46': 5.1, 'iris_47': 4.6, 'iris_48': 5.3, 'iris_49': 5.0, 'iris_50': 7.0, 'iris_51': 6.4, 'iris_52': 6.9, 'iris_53': 5.5, 'iris_54': 6.5, 'iris_55': 5.7, 'iris_56': 6.3, 'iris_57': 4.9, 'iris_58': 6.6, 'iris_59': 5.2, 'iris_60': 5.0, 'iris_61': 5.9, 'iris_62': 6.0, 'iris_63': 6.1, 'iris_64': 5.6, 'iris_65': 6.7, 'iris_66': 5.6, 'iris_67': 5.8, 'iris_68': 6.2, 'iris_69': 5.6, 'iris_70': 5.9, 'iris_71': 6.1, 'iris_72': 6.3, 'iris_73': 6.1, 'iris_74': 6.4, 'iris_75': 6.6, 'iris_76': 6.8, 'iris_77': 6.7, 'iris_78': 6.0, 'iris_79': 5.7, 'iris_80': 5.5, 'iris_81': 5.5, 'iris_82': 5.8, 'iris_83': 6.0, 'iris_84': 5.4, 'iris_85': 6.0, 'iris_86': 6.7, 'iris_87': 6.3, 'iris_88': 5.6, 'iris_89': 5.5, 'iris_90': 5.5, 'iris_91': 6.1, 'iris_92': 5.8, 'iris_93': 5.0, 'iris_94': 5.6, 'iris_95': 5.7, 'iris_96': 5.7, 'iris_97': 6.2, 'iris_98': 5.1, 'iris_99': 5.7, 'iris_100': 6.3, 'iris_101': 5.8, 'iris_102': 7.1, 'iris_103': 6.3, 'iris_104': 6.5, 'iris_105': 7.6, 'iris_106': 4.9, 'iris_107': 7.3, 'iris_108': 6.7, 'iris_109': 7.2, 'iris_110': 6.5, 'iris_111': 6.4, 'iris_112': 6.8, 'iris_113': 5.7, 'iris_114': 5.8, 'iris_115': 6.4, 'iris_116': 6.5, 'iris_117': 7.7, 'iris_118': 7.7, 'iris_119': 6.0, 'iris_120': 6.9, 'iris_121': 5.6, 'iris_122': 7.7, 'iris_123': 6.3, 'iris_124': 6.7, 'iris_125': 7.2, 'iris_126': 6.2, 'iris_127': 6.1, 'iris_128': 6.4, 'iris_129': 7.2, 'iris_130': 7.4, 'iris_131': 7.9, 'iris_132': 6.4, 'iris_133': 6.3, 'iris_134': 6.1, 'iris_135': 7.7, 'iris_136': 6.3, 'iris_137': 6.4, 'iris_138': 6.0, 'iris_139': 6.9, 'iris_140': 6.7, 'iris_141': 6.9, 'iris_142': 5.8, 'iris_143': 6.8, 'iris_144': 6.7, 'iris_145': 6.7, 'iris_146': 6.3, 'iris_147': 6.5, 'iris_148': 6.2, 'iris_149': 5.9}, 'sepal_width': {'iris_0': 3.5, 'iris_1': 3.0, 'iris_2': 3.2, 'iris_3': 3.1, 'iris_4': 3.6, 'iris_5': 3.9, 'iris_6': 3.4, 'iris_7': 3.4, 'iris_8': 2.9, 'iris_9': 3.1, 'iris_10': 3.7, 'iris_11': 3.4, 'iris_12': 3.0, 'iris_13': 3.0, 'iris_14': 4.0, 'iris_15': 4.4, 'iris_16': 3.9, 'iris_17': 3.5, 'iris_18': 3.8, 'iris_19': 3.8, 'iris_20': 3.4, 'iris_21': 3.7, 'iris_22': 3.6, 'iris_23': 3.3, 'iris_24': 3.4, 'iris_25': 3.0, 'iris_26': 3.4, 'iris_27': 3.5, 'iris_28': 3.4, 'iris_29': 3.2, 'iris_30': 3.1, 'iris_31': 3.4, 'iris_32': 4.1, 'iris_33': 4.2, 'iris_34': 3.1, 'iris_35': 3.2, 'iris_36': 3.5, 'iris_37': 3.6, 'iris_38': 3.0, 'iris_39': 3.4, 'iris_40': 3.5, 'iris_41': 2.3, 'iris_42': 3.2, 'iris_43': 3.5, 'iris_44': 3.8, 'iris_45': 3.0, 'iris_46': 3.8, 'iris_47': 3.2, 'iris_48': 3.7, 'iris_49': 3.3, 'iris_50': 3.2, 'iris_51': 3.2, 'iris_52': 3.1, 'iris_53': 2.3, 'iris_54': 2.8, 'iris_55': 2.8, 'iris_56': 3.3, 'iris_57': 2.4, 'iris_58': 2.9, 'iris_59': 2.7, 'iris_60': 2.0, 'iris_61': 3.0, 'iris_62': 2.2, 'iris_63': 2.9, 'iris_64': 2.9, 'iris_65': 3.1, 'iris_66': 3.0, 'iris_67': 2.7, 'iris_68': 2.2, 'iris_69': 2.5, 'iris_70': 3.2, 'iris_71': 2.8, 'iris_72': 2.5, 'iris_73': 2.8, 'iris_74': 2.9, 'iris_75': 3.0, 'iris_76': 2.8, 'iris_77': 3.0, 'iris_78': 2.9, 'iris_79': 2.6, 'iris_80': 2.4, 'iris_81': 2.4, 'iris_82': 2.7, 'iris_83': 2.7, 'iris_84': 3.0, 'iris_85': 3.4, 'iris_86': 3.1, 'iris_87': 2.3, 'iris_88': 3.0, 'iris_89': 2.5, 'iris_90': 2.6, 'iris_91': 3.0, 'iris_92': 2.6, 'iris_93': 2.3, 'iris_94': 2.7, 'iris_95': 3.0, 'iris_96': 2.9, 'iris_97': 2.9, 'iris_98': 2.5, 'iris_99': 2.8, 'iris_100': 3.3, 'iris_101': 2.7, 'iris_102': 3.0, 'iris_103': 2.9, 'iris_104': 3.0, 'iris_105': 3.0, 'iris_106': 2.5, 'iris_107': 2.9, 'iris_108': 2.5, 'iris_109': 3.6, 'iris_110': 3.2, 'iris_111': 2.7, 'iris_112': 3.0, 'iris_113': 2.5, 'iris_114': 2.8, 'iris_115': 3.2, 'iris_116': 3.0, 'iris_117': 3.8, 'iris_118': 2.6, 'iris_119': 2.2, 'iris_120': 3.2, 'iris_121': 2.8, 'iris_122': 2.8, 'iris_123': 2.7, 'iris_124': 3.3, 'iris_125': 3.2, 'iris_126': 2.8, 'iris_127': 3.0, 'iris_128': 2.8, 'iris_129': 3.0, 'iris_130': 2.8, 'iris_131': 3.8, 'iris_132': 2.8, 'iris_133': 2.8, 'iris_134': 2.6, 'iris_135': 3.0, 'iris_136': 3.4, 'iris_137': 3.1, 'iris_138': 3.0, 'iris_139': 3.1, 'iris_140': 3.1, 'iris_141': 3.1, 'iris_142': 2.7, 'iris_143': 3.2, 'iris_144': 3.3, 'iris_145': 3.0, 'iris_146': 2.5, 'iris_147': 3.0, 'iris_148': 3.4, 'iris_149': 3.0}, 'petal_length': {'iris_0': 1.4, 'iris_1': 1.4, 'iris_2': 1.3, 'iris_3': 1.5, 'iris_4': 1.4, 'iris_5': 1.7, 'iris_6': 1.4, 'iris_7': 1.5, 'iris_8': 1.4, 'iris_9': 1.5, 'iris_10': 1.5, 'iris_11': 1.6, 'iris_12': 1.4, 'iris_13': 1.1, 'iris_14': 1.2, 'iris_15': 1.5, 'iris_16': 1.3, 'iris_17': 1.4, 'iris_18': 1.7, 'iris_19': 1.5, 'iris_20': 1.7, 'iris_21': 1.5, 'iris_22': 1.0, 'iris_23': 1.7, 'iris_24': 1.9, 'iris_25': 1.6, 'iris_26': 1.6, 'iris_27': 1.5, 'iris_28': 1.4, 'iris_29': 1.6, 'iris_30': 1.6, 'iris_31': 1.5, 'iris_32': 1.5, 'iris_33': 1.4, 'iris_34': 1.5, 'iris_35': 1.2, 'iris_36': 1.3, 'iris_37': 1.4, 'iris_38': 1.3, 'iris_39': 1.5, 'iris_40': 1.3, 'iris_41': 1.3, 'iris_42': 1.3, 'iris_43': 1.6, 'iris_44': 1.9, 'iris_45': 1.4, 'iris_46': 1.6, 'iris_47': 1.4, 'iris_48': 1.5, 'iris_49': 1.4, 'iris_50': 4.7, 'iris_51': 4.5, 'iris_52': 4.9, 'iris_53': 4.0, 'iris_54': 4.6, 'iris_55': 4.5, 'iris_56': 4.7, 'iris_57': 3.3, 'iris_58': 4.6, 'iris_59': 3.9, 'iris_60': 3.5, 'iris_61': 4.2, 'iris_62': 4.0, 'iris_63': 4.7, 'iris_64': 3.6, 'iris_65': 4.4, 'iris_66': 4.5, 'iris_67': 4.1, 'iris_68': 4.5, 'iris_69': 3.9, 'iris_70': 4.8, 'iris_71': 4.0, 'iris_72': 4.9, 'iris_73': 4.7, 'iris_74': 4.3, 'iris_75': 4.4, 'iris_76': 4.8, 'iris_77': 5.0, 'iris_78': 4.5, 'iris_79': 3.5, 'iris_80': 3.8, 'iris_81': 3.7, 'iris_82': 3.9, 'iris_83': 5.1, 'iris_84': 4.5, 'iris_85': 4.5, 'iris_86': 4.7, 'iris_87': 4.4, 'iris_88': 4.1, 'iris_89': 4.0, 'iris_90': 4.4, 'iris_91': 4.6, 'iris_92': 4.0, 'iris_93': 3.3, 'iris_94': 4.2, 'iris_95': 4.2, 'iris_96': 4.2, 'iris_97': 4.3, 'iris_98': 3.0, 'iris_99': 4.1, 'iris_100': 6.0, 'iris_101': 5.1, 'iris_102': 5.9, 'iris_103': 5.6, 'iris_104': 5.8, 'iris_105': 6.6, 'iris_106': 4.5, 'iris_107': 6.3, 'iris_108': 5.8, 'iris_109': 6.1, 'iris_110': 5.1, 'iris_111': 5.3, 'iris_112': 5.5, 'iris_113': 5.0, 'iris_114': 5.1, 'iris_115': 5.3, 'iris_116': 5.5, 'iris_117': 6.7, 'iris_118': 6.9, 'iris_119': 5.0, 'iris_120': 5.7, 'iris_121': 4.9, 'iris_122': 6.7, 'iris_123': 4.9, 'iris_124': 5.7, 'iris_125': 6.0, 'iris_126': 4.8, 'iris_127': 4.9, 'iris_128': 5.6, 'iris_129': 5.8, 'iris_130': 6.1, 'iris_131': 6.4, 'iris_132': 5.6, 'iris_133': 5.1, 'iris_134': 5.6, 'iris_135': 6.1, 'iris_136': 5.6, 'iris_137': 5.5, 'iris_138': 4.8, 'iris_139': 5.4, 'iris_140': 5.6, 'iris_141': 5.1, 'iris_142': 5.1, 'iris_143': 5.9, 'iris_144': 5.7, 'iris_145': 5.2, 'iris_146': 5.0, 'iris_147': 5.2, 'iris_148': 5.4, 'iris_149': 5.1}, 'petal_width': {'iris_0': 0.2, 'iris_1': 0.2, 'iris_2': 0.2, 'iris_3': 0.2, 'iris_4': 0.2, 'iris_5': 0.4, 'iris_6': 0.3, 'iris_7': 0.2, 'iris_8': 0.2, 'iris_9': 0.1, 'iris_10': 0.2, 'iris_11': 0.2, 'iris_12': 0.1, 'iris_13': 0.1, 'iris_14': 0.2, 'iris_15': 0.4, 'iris_16': 0.4, 'iris_17': 0.3, 'iris_18': 0.3, 'iris_19': 0.3, 'iris_20': 0.2, 'iris_21': 0.4, 'iris_22': 0.2, 'iris_23': 0.5, 'iris_24': 0.2, 'iris_25': 0.2, 'iris_26': 0.4, 'iris_27': 0.2, 'iris_28': 0.2, 'iris_29': 0.2, 'iris_30': 0.2, 'iris_31': 0.4, 'iris_32': 0.1, 'iris_33': 0.2, 'iris_34': 0.2, 'iris_35': 0.2, 'iris_36': 0.2, 'iris_37': 0.1, 'iris_38': 0.2, 'iris_39': 0.2, 'iris_40': 0.3, 'iris_41': 0.3, 'iris_42': 0.2, 'iris_43': 0.6, 'iris_44': 0.4, 'iris_45': 0.3, 'iris_46': 0.2, 'iris_47': 0.2, 'iris_48': 0.2, 'iris_49': 0.2, 'iris_50': 1.4, 'iris_51': 1.5, 'iris_52': 1.5, 'iris_53': 1.3, 'iris_54': 1.5, 'iris_55': 1.3, 'iris_56': 1.6, 'iris_57': 1.0, 'iris_58': 1.3, 'iris_59': 1.4, 'iris_60': 1.0, 'iris_61': 1.5, 'iris_62': 1.0, 'iris_63': 1.4, 'iris_64': 1.3, 'iris_65': 1.4, 'iris_66': 1.5, 'iris_67': 1.0, 'iris_68': 1.5, 'iris_69': 1.1, 'iris_70': 1.8, 'iris_71': 1.3, 'iris_72': 1.5, 'iris_73': 1.2, 'iris_74': 1.3, 'iris_75': 1.4, 'iris_76': 1.4, 'iris_77': 1.7, 'iris_78': 1.5, 'iris_79': 1.0, 'iris_80': 1.1, 'iris_81': 1.0, 'iris_82': 1.2, 'iris_83': 1.6, 'iris_84': 1.5, 'iris_85': 1.6, 'iris_86': 1.5, 'iris_87': 1.3, 'iris_88': 1.3, 'iris_89': 1.3, 'iris_90': 1.2, 'iris_91': 1.4, 'iris_92': 1.2, 'iris_93': 1.0, 'iris_94': 1.3, 'iris_95': 1.2, 'iris_96': 1.3, 'iris_97': 1.3, 'iris_98': 1.1, 'iris_99': 1.3, 'iris_100': 2.5, 'iris_101': 1.9, 'iris_102': 2.1, 'iris_103': 1.8, 'iris_104': 2.2, 'iris_105': 2.1, 'iris_106': 1.7, 'iris_107': 1.8, 'iris_108': 1.8, 'iris_109': 2.5, 'iris_110': 2.0, 'iris_111': 1.9, 'iris_112': 2.1, 'iris_113': 2.0, 'iris_114': 2.4, 'iris_115': 2.3, 'iris_116': 1.8, 'iris_117': 2.2, 'iris_118': 2.3, 'iris_119': 1.5, 'iris_120': 2.3, 'iris_121': 2.0, 'iris_122': 2.0, 'iris_123': 1.8, 'iris_124': 2.1, 'iris_125': 1.8, 'iris_126': 1.8, 'iris_127': 1.8, 'iris_128': 2.1, 'iris_129': 1.6, 'iris_130': 1.9, 'iris_131': 2.0, 'iris_132': 2.2, 'iris_133': 1.5, 'iris_134': 1.4, 'iris_135': 2.3, 'iris_136': 2.4, 'iris_137': 1.8, 'iris_138': 1.8, 'iris_139': 2.1, 'iris_140': 2.4, 'iris_141': 2.3, 'iris_142': 1.9, 'iris_143': 2.3, 'iris_144': 2.5, 'iris_145': 2.3, 'iris_146': 1.9, 'iris_147': 2.0, 'iris_148': 2.3, 'iris_149': 1.8}})
y_iris = pd.Series({'iris_0': 'setosa', 'iris_1': 'setosa', 'iris_2': 'setosa', 'iris_3': 'setosa', 'iris_4': 'setosa', 'iris_5': 'setosa', 'iris_6': 'setosa', 'iris_7': 'setosa', 'iris_8': 'setosa', 'iris_9': 'setosa', 'iris_10': 'setosa', 'iris_11': 'setosa', 'iris_12': 'setosa', 'iris_13': 'setosa', 'iris_14': 'setosa', 'iris_15': 'setosa', 'iris_16': 'setosa', 'iris_17': 'setosa', 'iris_18': 'setosa', 'iris_19': 'setosa', 'iris_20': 'setosa', 'iris_21': 'setosa', 'iris_22': 'setosa', 'iris_23': 'setosa', 'iris_24': 'setosa', 'iris_25': 'setosa', 'iris_26': 'setosa', 'iris_27': 'setosa', 'iris_28': 'setosa', 'iris_29': 'setosa', 'iris_30': 'setosa', 'iris_31': 'setosa', 'iris_32': 'setosa', 'iris_33': 'setosa', 'iris_34': 'setosa', 'iris_35': 'setosa', 'iris_36': 'setosa', 'iris_37': 'setosa', 'iris_38': 'setosa', 'iris_39': 'setosa', 'iris_40': 'setosa', 'iris_41': 'setosa', 'iris_42': 'setosa', 'iris_43': 'setosa', 'iris_44': 'setosa', 'iris_45': 'setosa', 'iris_46': 'setosa', 'iris_47': 'setosa', 'iris_48': 'setosa', 'iris_49': 'setosa', 'iris_50': 'versicolor', 'iris_51': 'versicolor', 'iris_52': 'versicolor', 'iris_53': 'versicolor', 'iris_54': 'versicolor', 'iris_55': 'versicolor', 'iris_56': 'versicolor', 'iris_57': 'versicolor', 'iris_58': 'versicolor', 'iris_59': 'versicolor', 'iris_60': 'versicolor', 'iris_61': 'versicolor', 'iris_62': 'versicolor', 'iris_63': 'versicolor', 'iris_64': 'versicolor', 'iris_65': 'versicolor', 'iris_66': 'versicolor', 'iris_67': 'versicolor', 'iris_68': 'versicolor', 'iris_69': 'versicolor', 'iris_70': 'versicolor', 'iris_71': 'versicolor', 'iris_72': 'versicolor', 'iris_73': 'versicolor', 'iris_74': 'versicolor', 'iris_75': 'versicolor', 'iris_76': 'versicolor', 'iris_77': 'versicolor', 'iris_78': 'versicolor', 'iris_79': 'versicolor', 'iris_80': 'versicolor', 'iris_81': 'versicolor', 'iris_82': 'versicolor', 'iris_83': 'versicolor', 'iris_84': 'versicolor', 'iris_85': 'versicolor', 'iris_86': 'versicolor', 'iris_87': 'versicolor', 'iris_88': 'versicolor', 'iris_89': 'versicolor', 'iris_90': 'versicolor', 'iris_91': 'versicolor', 'iris_92': 'versicolor', 'iris_93': 'versicolor', 'iris_94': 'versicolor', 'iris_95': 'versicolor', 'iris_96': 'versicolor', 'iris_97': 'versicolor', 'iris_98': 'versicolor', 'iris_99': 'versicolor', 'iris_100': 'virginica', 'iris_101': 'virginica', 'iris_102': 'virginica', 'iris_103': 'virginica', 'iris_104': 'virginica', 'iris_105': 'virginica', 'iris_106': 'virginica', 'iris_107': 'virginica', 'iris_108': 'virginica', 'iris_109': 'virginica', 'iris_110': 'virginica', 'iris_111': 'virginica', 'iris_112': 'virginica', 'iris_113': 'virginica', 'iris_114': 'virginica', 'iris_115': 'virginica', 'iris_116': 'virginica', 'iris_117': 'virginica', 'iris_118': 'virginica', 'iris_119': 'virginica', 'iris_120': 'virginica', 'iris_121': 'virginica', 'iris_122': 'virginica', 'iris_123': 'virginica', 'iris_124': 'virginica', 'iris_125': 'virginica', 'iris_126': 'virginica', 'iris_127': 'virginica', 'iris_128': 'virginica', 'iris_129': 'virginica', 'iris_130': 'virginica', 'iris_131': 'virginica', 'iris_132': 'virginica', 'iris_133': 'virginica', 'iris_134': 'virginica', 'iris_135': 'virginica', 'iris_136': 'virginica', 'iris_137': 'virginica', 'iris_138': 'virginica', 'iris_139': 'virginica', 'iris_140': 'virginica', 'iris_141': 'virginica', 'iris_142': 'virginica', 'iris_143': 'virginica', 'iris_144': 'virginica', 'iris_145': 'virginica', 'iris_146': 'virginica', 'iris_147': 'virginica', 'iris_148': 'virginica', 'iris_149': 'virginica'})
c_iris = pd.Series({'setosa': '#66c2a5', 'versicolor': '#fc8d62', 'virginica': '#8da0cb'})

# Get edge to weight mapping
weights = X_iris.T.corr().stack()
weights.index = weights.index.map(frozenset)
print(weights.size)
# 22500 = 150**2

# Get rid of diagonal b/c the weights are non-informative
weights = weights[weights.index.map(lambda nodes: len(nodes) == 2)]
print(weights.size)
# 22350 = 150**2 - 150

# Get non-redundant edges ([upper/lower]triangle)
weights = pd.Series(weights.to_dict() )
print(weights.size)
# 11175 = (150**2 - 150)/2

# Create graph
tol = 0.99
graph = nx.Graph()
for edge, w in weights.abs().items(): # For sake of demonstration, just take absolute value though I wouldn't normally do this
    if w > tol:
        graph.add_edge(*edge, weight=w)
    
# Get positions
pos = nx.circular_layout(graph)#, seed=0)

# Prepare nodes for HoloViews
df_nodes = pd.DataFrame(pos, index=list("xy")).T
df_nodes.index.name = "Node"
df_nodes["Species"] = y_iris
df_nodes = df_nodes.reset_index()[["x","y", "Node", "Species"]]
df_nodes.head()
#   x   y   Node    Species
# 0 0.002421    -0.765592   iris_1  setosa
# 1 0.116149    -0.721862   iris_0  setosa
# 2 0.012620    -0.730962   iris_2  setosa
# 3 0.053972    -0.611302   iris_3  setosa
# 4 0.049840    -0.687669   iris_4  setosa

# Prepare edges for HoloViews
df_edges = list()
for node_a, node_b, edge_data in graph.edges(data=True):
    df_edges.append([node_a, node_b, edge_data["weight"]])
df_edges = pd.DataFrame(df_edges, columns=["start", "end", "weight"])
df_edges.head()
# start end weight
# 0 iris_1  iris_0  0.995999
# 1 iris_1  iris_2  0.996607
# 2 iris_1  iris_3  0.997397
# 3 iris_1  iris_4  0.992233
# 4 iris_1  iris_5  0.993592


hv_nodes = hv.Nodes(df_nodes)
hv_graph = hv.Graph((df_edges, hv_nodes), label='Iris Dataset')
hv_graph.opts(cmap=c_iris.to_dict(), node_size=10, edge_line_width="weight",
              node_line_color='white', node_color='Species', xaxis=None, yaxis=None)
```

[image]

```
# Custom mapping
categories = list(map(lambda i: "Category_{}".format(i), range(10)))
range_of_values = np.linspace(0,1)

node_to_custom = dict()
for i, node in enumerate(graph.nodes()):
    rng = np.random.RandomState(i)
    # Get a random number of categories (real data will not be this obviously)
    number_of_categories = rng.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5], size=1)[0]
    # Grab N categories w/o replacement
    categories_wrt_node = rng.choice(categories, size=number_of_categories, replace=False)
    # Get values ranging from [0,1] for those categories
    values_wrt_categories = rng.choice(range_of_values, size=number_of_categories )
    # Get a mapping between categories and values
    categories_to_values = pd.Series(dict(zip(categories_wrt_node, values_wrt_categories)), dtype=float)
    # Get non-zero values, sort, and store
    node_to_custom[node] = categories_to_values[lambda v: v > 0].sort_values(ascending=False)
    
# Example of {key:value} showing {node:series}
list(node_to_custom.items())[0]

# ('iris_1',
#  Category_2    0.734694
#  Category_9    0.489796
#  Category_8    0.469388
#  Category_4    0.122449
#  dtype: float64)
```

Comment: bokeh HoverTool must have a static number of fields per tool object. You would have to add separate tooltips to each glyph separately (which means you would need to create your nodes separately as well)

Comment: @gshpychka so for this route would be able to use holoviews still or would this need to be entirely in bokeh?  Also, is it possible to modify the existing nodes to add these extra fields?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer to your question, but maybe I can still help.

To the best of my knowledge, Holoviews doesn't support variable number of tooltips. What it does support are custom tooltips.

Custom tooltips look like this:

```
# each tuple will be a row in the tooltip
tooltips = [
    ('Name', '@name'),
    ('Symbol', '@symbol'),
    ('CPK', '$color[hex, swatch]:CPK')
]
custom_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
points.opts(tools=[custom_hover_tool])
```

Example from here:
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html

More details on the usable $variables and @variables:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool

So if this could be good enough for you, you could aggregate your categorical data into a string for each record like "Category_2: 0.734694, Category_9: 0.489796 ..." and display that as a row in the tooltip with a label like "Categories:".

But the `tooltips` variable actually can be an HTML template too, something like this:

```
tooltips = """
<div class="row">
  <div class="col label">Node</div>
  <div class="col value">@name</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col label">Species</div>
  <div class="col value">@species</div>
</div>
@categories{safe}
"""
```

The `{safe}` part forces the tooltip to display the content of that variable as HTML content. So this time you have to previously aggregate your categorical data into a data column that already contains the final HTML code for every record, so for your example record it should look like this:

```
'\
<div class="row">\
  <div class="col label">Category_2:</div>\
  <div class="col value">0.734694</div>\
</div>\
<div class="row">\
  <div class="col label">Category_9:</div>\
  <div class="col value">0.489796</div>\
</div>\
...\
'
```

(Most likely you would have two for loops inside each other, one for every node and another for every category in it, and only adding one "row" at the time, but something like this would be the end result for each node.)

If you use the exact same HTML/CSS structure in both code blocks, they should be merged seamlessly.

Treat these code blocks as mockups just to demonstrate the idea as I just improvised them here without testing, but I hope it helps.
Let me know if you tried it and show me a working example if you got stuck with it and I try to go into the details.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out about this!  I will take a dive into this in a few.  It's fairly complex so I'll need to read up about it but this points me in the right direction.